# Cakephp HABTM: View generating drop down instead of multi value selectbox

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am trying to work with HABTM association between Profiles and Qualifications tables.

Model: Profile.php

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Profile extends AppModel {
  public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Qualification' => array(
    'className' => 'Qualification',
    'joinTable' => 'profile_qualifications',
    'foreignKey' => 'profile_id',
    'associationForeignKey' => 'qualification_id',
    'unique' => 'keepExisting'
    )
  );
}
```

Model: Qualification.php

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Qualification extends AppModel {
  public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Profile' => array(
    'className' => 'Profile',
    'joinTable' => 'profile_qualifications',
    'foreignKey' => 'qualification_id',
    'associationForeignKey' => 'profile_id',
    'unique' => 'keepExisting',
    )
  );
}
```

Controller: ProfilesController.php

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class ProfilesController extends AppController {
  public function edit() {
    $this->Profile->id = $this->Auth->user('profile_id');
    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
      if ($this->Profile->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The profile has been saved'));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view'));
      } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The profile could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
      }
    } else {
      $this->request->data = $this->Profile->read(null, $this->Auth->user('profile_id'));
    }
    $salutations = $this->Profile->Salutation->find('list', array('fields' => array('Salutation.id', 'Salutation.abbr_name')));
    $qualifications = $this->Profile->Qualification->find('list', array('fields' => array('Qualification.id', 'Qualification.abbr_name')));
    $this->set(compact('salutations', 'qualifications'));
  }
}
```

Vew: edit.ctp

```
<div class="profiles form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Profile'); ?>
  <fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('My Profile'); ?></legend>
<?php
  echo $this->Form->input('salutation_id');
  echo $this->Form->input('first_name');
  echo $this->Form->input('middle_name');
  echo $this->Form->input('last_name');
  echo $this->Form->input('qualification'); /* gives drop down not multi select */
  echo $this->Form->input('bio');
  echo $this->Form->input('email');
  echo $this->Form->input('mobile');
  echo $this->Form->input('phone');
?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
```

The edit view thus generated contains drop down to select a single value at a time for Qualifications attribute.

I want to know how can I generate a view with multi value selection box for qualifications ?
Moreover, what is the mistake in my code right now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```php
echo $this->Form->input('qualification');
```

to

```php
echo $this->Form->input('qualification', array(
    'multiple' => true
));
```

The CakePHP manual has more information on the form helper [input options](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options).

Comment: Yes! this worked for me. Getting the correct select box now... but why do I need to do it manually because this should work automatically ?

Comment: I think you're right, but I'm not sure how. The options are just an array with ids as keys and names as values, which could also be for a belongs to relationship.

Answer (score 3):

First time poster, long time user.

I stumbled across this question today, and ended up using the subsequent solution which indeed does work quite nicely. However, I left myself wondering "why wouldn't CakePHP pickup on the HABTM relationship properly?" Especially considering (at least in my case) that the majority of the files had been baked in the cake console.

If we dive a little deeper into the issue, we discover that the problem is actually quite simple. A closer look at this snippet in the `PostsController.php` reveals how Cake builds in the HABTM relationship to the function, and uses `$this->set()` in order to pass it to the view (IMPORTANT: using lower-case plural versions "salutations"):

```
$salutations = $this->Profile->Salutation->find('list', array('fields' => array('Salutation.id', 'Salutation.abbr_name')));
$qualifications = $this->Profile->Qualification->find('list', array('fields' => array('Qualification.id', 'Qualification.abbr_name')));
$this->set(compact('salutations', 'qualifications'));
```

According to the Cake Cook Book, in order to take advantage of this HABTM in the front end when using the form helper is to specify the variable in **singular form & title case** (ie: "Salutation")

Snippet from the cook book:

> Assuming that User hasAndBelongsToMany Group. In your controller, set a camelCase plural variable (group -> groups in this case, or ExtraFunkyModel -> extraFunkyModels) with the select options. In the controller action you would put the following:
>
> ```
> $this->set('groups', $this->User->Group->find('list'));
> ```
>
> And in the view a multiple select can be created with this simple code:
>
> ```
> echo $this->Form->input('Group');
> ```

Should solve your issue without any necessary field tweaking.

Cheers!

Bake on.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you need further configuration of your input:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Qualification',array(
    'label' => 'Qualifications',
    'type' => 'select',
    'multiple' => true, // or 'checkbox' if you want a set of checkboxes
    'options' => $qualifications,
    'selected' => $html->value('Qualification.Qualification'),
));
```

I've used [this](http://mrphp.com.au/blog/working-habtm-form-data-cakephp) blog post whenever I've come up against HABTM associations. It seems to me that a set of checkboxes maybe desired by default over a select input - maybe someone with greater CakePHP insight can chime in here?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am able to see the multi select box now.

For some reason the changes you have mentioned did not work and then I changed '$form->' to '$this->Form->' which got the interface back instead of error. I think your code was for some earlier version of Cake. I am using 2.2.3

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @i01000001, I've updated my answer for future viewers